# Windows 10 tablet mode keeps opening new instances of desktop apps

Tags: windows-10, tablet-mode

When I run Windows 10 in tablet mode desktop apps icons on the start screen keep opening new instances of programs rather than bring the existing running instance to the front.

I noticed this when my tablet slowed down considerably and I found three instances of Outlook and several instances of Explorer running. (I assume the Explorer instances were really one instances with several windows.) Before I noticed that I was annoyed that I never returned to the current position in the program (for example a specific screen in Outlook) that I left before.

Is there some way to tell Windows 10 to be more consistent here and return to the running instance of a program (as it does with metro apps and with apps in desktop mode)?